# grep ouput filepath with file modified date?

Tags: linux, debian, grep

Is it possible to make the `grep` command to output file paths with file modified date like so:

```
12-02-2015 /file/path/to/the/file
16-02-2015 /file/path/to/the/file
25-02-2015 /file/path/to/the/file
03-04-2015 /file/path/to/the/file
```

or:

```
/file/path/to/the/file 12-02-2015
/file/path/to/the/file 12-02-2015
/file/path/to/the/file 12-02-2015
/file/path/to/the/file 12-02-2015
```

Answer (score 8):

`grep` itself has no functionality for that. But you can use `awk`. Use that syntax:

```
grep -Hr pattern . | awk -F: '{"stat -c %z "$1 | getline r; print r": "$0 }'
```

That forces `grep` to print the filenames `-H`. `-r` means search recusive in the given directory `.`. `awk`'s field separator is set to `:`. The first varibale `$1` now contains the filename. `awk` calls `stat -c %z` on each filename, which gives the modification time in human readable format. That is saved into the variable `r`, which is printed in front of each search result.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more understandable alternative using xargs

```
grep -rl pattern | xargs stat -c %n':'%z | awk -F: '{print $1}'
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out you can use `find -exec` to do this. The following is not a complete example as it does not output quite the format requested.

```
 find . -exec grep -q set {} \; -exec stat -c "%y %n" {} \;
```

> ...
>
> 2019-06-03 11:46:14.565890000 -0700 ./bin/tkdiff_helper.sh
>
> 2018-04-24 12:00:02.389077000 -0700 ./bin/start_vnc.older 2019-09-04
>
> 08:41:49.021891000 -0700 ./bin/calmdpv_2016
>
> ...

The second exec only runs if grep finds a match.

`-q` is to quite grep.

Comment: Just realized `date +%D -r file` or `date +%F -r file` would do nicely too.

Comment: Something like `find . -exec grep -q set {} \; -exec echo -n "{} "  \; -exec date +%F -r  {} \; `

Answer (score 0):

The grep utility isn't isn't designed for that, but for filtering lines of a file or in a command output instead. What you can do is to combine it with awk through a pipe to get what you want, like that:

```
find . -iname 'file-you-want-to-find' -exec stat -c "%y %n" {} \; | awk '{ print $4 " " $1 }' | grep 'date-you-are-looking-for'
```

Best regards.